# Types of financial derivatives

Tags: derivatives, trading, exotics

I am looking for an explanation for different types/grades of derivatives.

For example we have various asset classes:

- equities
- FX (currency)
- derivatives, etc.

Or different types of secured debts, like:

1. junior
2. mezzanine
3. senior
4. s-senior.

So my question is about the same things, but for different types of derivatives.
Is there any classification of them? I know that, there are `plain vanilla derivatives` or *vanilla* as they usually called. For example, - E/A option on equity. Things with options on futures, where underlying asset is FX are more complicated than that. And there are some `exotic` things like: swaptions or XCCYs.

I know that different financial institution can count that one thing is `exotic` enough for them, and for other it will be `not-exotic` enough. As I understand it's usually depends on some `in-house` metrics. But how does work in ordinary way?

I am looking not for academic answer, but if you have any source/literature, I'll be glad if you share it.

Comment: I woud start with the lists of derivatives that can be specified with FpML https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FpML / FIX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange .

Comment: I have never seen a full classification, but I will stick my neck out and say that there are only 4 types of derivatives: (1) Futures and Forwards (2) Options (3) Swaps (4) "Tranched" securities like mortage securities, CDS etc.

Comment: @DimitriVulis, thank you. To be honest I have read couple of wiki articles of OTC derivatives, but I also don't know for sure, does ISDA provide any classification?

Comment: @noob2. well, I know that, especially CDS, but I also never seen full/any classification/stigmatization. Yes, we called it standardised OTC instruments sometimes, like: CDS, XCCY, IRS, OIS, etc. But as you, I never seen any table with explanation/description of something like it.

Comment: Most desks have some "permitted products list" (PPL). I'd also look at the definitional booklets https://www.isda.org/books#jump-2  that go with the ISDA master agreement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISDA_Master_Agreement , but I don't think they're free.

Comment: I very grateful for provided information, Dmitry. I'll mark this question as answered if would you combine all you comments together as an answer.

Comment: I have found ISDA taxonomy v2 draft (https://www.isda.org/a/ROqME/ISDA-Taxonomy-EQ-CR-FX-IR-v2.0-30-August-2019-DRAFT.xls) very informative for me. If you would like to combine your comments together, and form them as an answer, I'll mark this question as answered and suggest an  upvote.